# QOCI plugin making error QT

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, qmake, qoci

I faced some problems when I was trying to make a QOCI driver for QT 5.7.

I was folloing this Guide ([How to build Qt QOCI (Oracle Database driver) on Windows with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601662/how-to-build-qt-qoci-oracle-database-driver-on-windows-with-mingw)) and it helped before the "Third try".

When after the "Second try" I call **mingw32-make** I have such a mistake `debug\qsqlocid_resource_res.o no such file or directory`

In Make.Release file I have:

```
-LC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\include\lib -LC:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin -lQt5Sqld -lQt5Cored debug\qsqlocid_resource_res.o -LC:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\oci\lib\MSVC
```

and in In Make.Debug I have:

```
-LC:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\include\lib C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin debug\qsqlocid_resource_res.o -loci -lQt5Sqld4 -lQt5Cored  -LC:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\oci\lib\MSVC
```

So what I colud do wrong?